# Should Revelation 1:18 be translated, "I have the keys of Death and the Grave", or, "I have the keys of Death and Hades"?

Tags: jesus, revelation, death, resurrection

Revelation 1:18 NKJV translation:

> I am He who lives, and was dead, and behold, I am alive forevermore.
> Amen.
>
> And I have the keys of **Death** and of **Hades**.

Revelation 1:18 proposal translation:

> I am the Living One. I was dead, and behold now I am alive forevermore,
>
> and I have the keys of **Death** and **the Grave**.

My observations are that death shouldn't be capitalized, and "Hades" is merely the Greek work for the underworld of the dead, which is used to represent "the grave" as in being dead and buried in the earth. Because of this, is the Hebrew "Sheol" and the Greek "Hades" merely synonymous terms for the grave?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Many questions on the site indicate that _sheol_ may refer to either the grave or the afterlife. _Hades_ refers to the afterlife. Just put the words in the search box to see the various questions and answers covering this topic.

Comment: Your proposed translation and use of **grave** as opposed to **Hades** is too "individualistic". **Hades** speaks to the "common" grave of mankind and consequently is much more appropriate here.

Comment: What would you think if it was instead rendered, "**the Grave**"?

Comment: I guess you are talking to me here, so let me continue thus: I have long believed that **Hell/Sheol/Hades** is just **"the Grave"**, where "the dead" are conscious of nothing and are but returned to "dust". Hell should not be thought of as a place of *conscious* **eternal fiery torment**.  The "souls" of the dead, however, it would seem are held in some kind of "suspended animation", pending the resurrection of same. As to the "common" grave of mankind, alluded to above, this is not an individual burial place, or (simple) grave, nor is it an individual tomb.

Comment: @OldeEnglish I believe that all humans, the righteous and the unrighteous, perish upon death: their nephesh (life/being) is extinguished, and the spirit returns to God who gave it. The dead remain dead until they are resurrected by God. The righteous only get to heaven when Christ returns on the Day of the Lord to bring God's chosen into Paradise, en masse.

Comment: The physical body is extinguished, but not so much the *nephesh/psykhe* (soul). The *ruach/pneuma* (spirit) is the "life-force" and consequently it is that, that is extinguished. One can't have their "life-force" returned to God. It's the "soul" that receives *potential* immortality, and consequently it is the "soul" that is returned to God, for Him to do with as He sees fit. Your last sentence is too general in its concept as one's *resurrection* can involve so much more, which we need not go into at this juncture. Paradise, of course, is all relative, there being more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some translations that don't capitalize Death. Such as:

Revelation 1:18 King James Version

> 18 I am he that liveth, and was dead; and, behold, I am alive for
> evermore, Amen; and have the keys of **hell and of death.**

Revelation 1:18 New International Version

> 18 I am the Living One; I was dead, and now look, I am alive for ever
> and ever! And I hold the keys of **death and Hades.**

[These](https://biblehub.com/strongs/revelation/1-18.htm) are the relevant words:

**Death**
θανάτου (thanatou)
Noun - Genitive Masculine Singular
Strong's Greek 2288: Death, physical or spiritual. From thnesko; death.

**[2288 thánatos](https://biblehub.com/greek/2288.htm)** (derived from 2348 /thnḗskō, "to die") – physical or spiritual death; (figuratively) separation from the life (salvation) of God forever by dying without first experiencing death to self to receive His gift of salvation.

**Hades.**
ᾅδου (hadou)
Noun - Genitive Masculine Singular
Strong's Greek 86: Hades, the unseen world. Properly, unseen, i.e. 'Hades' or the place of departed souls.

**[86 hádēs](https://biblehub.com/greek/86.htm)** (from 1 /A "not" and idein/eidō, "see") – properly, the "unseen place," referring to the (invisible) realm in which all the dead reside, i.e. the present dwelling place of all the departed (deceased); Hades.

gotquestions says:

> In the Hebrew Scriptures, the word used to describe the realm of the
> dead is sheol. It simply means “the place of the dead” or “the place
> of departed souls/spirits.” The New Testament Greek equivalent to
> sheol is hades, which is also a general reference to “the place of the
> dead.” Sheol/hades is divided into a place of blessing (where Lazarus
> was in Luke 16) and a place of torment (where the rich man was in Luke
> 16). Sheol also seems to be a temporary place where souls are kept as
> they await the final resurrection. The souls of the righteous, at
> death, go directly into the presence of God—the part of sheol called
> “heaven,” “paradise,” or “Abraham’s bosom” (Luke 23:43; 2 Corinthians
> 5:8; Philippians 1:23).

Let me quote a paper titled [Sheol and Hades in Old and New Testament](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/003463733803500304?journalCode=raeb#:%7E:text=To%20the%20Hebrew%20mind%20Sheol,of%20departed%20spirits%2C%20or%20personalities.)
by Fred B. Pearson, Th.D

> To the Hebrew mind Sheol was simply the state or abode of the dead. It
> was not the same as the grave, though it was so translated in some of
> the older versions. **The grave was the resting place of the body from
> which the spirit had departed, while Sheol was the resting place of
> departed spirits, or personalities.**

While I think it is possible to translate Hades as grave according to

> **Strong's Exhaustive Concordance** grave, hell. From a (as negative particle) and eido; properly, unseen, i.e. "Hades" or the place
> (state) of departed souls -- grave, hell. [[1]](https://biblehub.com/greek/86.htm)

I believe it would confuse the English reader because there were other words that were meant to refer to the grave. Such as:

**[Strong's Greek: 5028.](https://biblehub.com/greek/5028.htm)** τάφος (taphos) -- a burial, hence a **grave**
... Bible Strong's Greek 5028 5028. taphos Strong's Concordance taphos: a burial, hence a **grave** Original Word: τάφος, ου, ὁ Part of Speech: Noun, Masculine Transliteration: taphos Phonetic Spelling: (taf' os) Definition ...

**[Strong's Greek: 3419.](https://biblehub.com/greek/3419.htm)** μνημεῖον (mnémeion) -- a memorial, a monument
... Genesis 23:6 , 9 ; Genesis 50:5 ; Isaiah 22:16 , etc. *Strong's Exhaustive Concordance:* **grave**, sepulcher, tomb. From mneme ; a remembrance, i.e. Cenotaph (place of interment)- **grave** ...

**[Strong's Greek: 3418.](https://biblehub.com/greek/3418.htm)** μνῆμα (mnéma) -- a memorial, a sepulcher
... :9 (Josephus, Antiquities 7, 1, 3; the Sept. for קֶבֶר) . S*trong's Exhaustive Concordance:* **grave**, sepulcher, tomb. From mnaomai ; a memorial, i.e. Sepulchral monument (burial-place)- **grave**, ...

---

**What if taphos, mnemeion, and mnema are "a grave", but Hades is "the Grave"?**

Using "the Grave" as a translation for "Hades" could be considered accurate in the sense that it captures the general concept conveyed by the Greek term.

Whether to recommend such a change would depend. Things to consider are: the goal of the translation, the intended audience, and the theological implications.

I think it's important to recognize that "Hades" carries broader meaning in Greek mythology and Jewish thought. It encompasses not only the grave but also the realm of the dead and the concept of the afterlife. Therefore, while "the Grave" may accurately convey *one* aspect of the meaning of "Hades," **it may not capture its full meaning.**

That being said, "the Grave" **may offer a more accessible rendering** of "Hades" especially for people who have English as a second language. In this case, other translations may be more suitable for conveying the full depth and significance of the term.

Comment: @Jason_ What if taphos, mnemeion, and mnema are "**a grave**", but Hades is "**the Grave**"?

Comment: And with that, you fully answered my question. Thanks and God bless you!

Comment: @JoshuaB You're very welcome! I'm thrilled that I could provide you with the information you needed. If you have any more questions in the future or need me to clarify anything, don't hesitate to let me know. Wishing you all the best, and may you be blessed abundantly too!

Comment: My completely innocent and praiseworthy comments to you, Jason, not to mention your acknowledgement have been inexplicably removed. Have you any idea why this was deemed necessary??

Comment: @OldeEnglish I am likewise unsure. My best guess is that it was done in order to keep the site tidy.

Comment: Usually when this kind of "clean up" happens, it's as a result of someone taking the comment as a derogatory, for one reason or another, and then resorting to the "flag" option, which then brings in the moderators, to either leave the comment as is, or side with the duly offended. Someone (not necessarily you) may have taken my use of the word "exhaustive" out of context. However, according to google dictionary the meaning is: *examining, including, or considering all elements or aspects; fully comprehensive.*  My additional "College" comment was to all intents and purposes complementary.